# Crash when creating new instance(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel )

Tags: c#, dll

I run I the loop and after few times I would be able to create new instance.

```
if (this.excelApp == null)
        {
            this.excelApp = new Application();
        }
```

The error in the dll and I stuck with dialog error message from dll. Until I will close the dialog my code is freezing and I can't continue. If I wrap in try/catch it will not help because it dialog.How can I kill this dialog or solve this problem?

[image: Error message]

Comment: 1. do not excel interop if all you wana do is to create excel file - there are libraries which can build excel file for you 2. close application properly 3. or use the same instance of appication .... I bet that if you open task manager you will see multiple excel.exe and prolly this is out of memory problem ... (also windows 7? you will be doomed soon)

Comment: do not excel interop-The project already done.What can I use ?

Comment: export to excel can be done with Open XML SDK

Comment: Is it interop only for Windows 7?

Comment: *Is it interop only for Windows 7?* no, it was off-topic part of the comment ... just saw the window it's from W7 and it will lost support soon

Comment: I see I have multi times excel .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

firstly I would always send this to open in the background 
 you can do it this way (h/t SO)

```
this.excelApp.Visible = false;
```

Which will help avoid the dialog.

You can also open the file itself thusly (also H/T SO), which also runs Excel hidden.

```
var  xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"/path", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
......        
xlWorkBook.Close();
```

Then at the end of each loop I normally call this as sometimes the processes will hang around. Full disclosure, I'm only reading and copying from excel so I don't have to worry about waiting on a write concluding.

```
 private static void KillExcel()
        {
            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("excel"))
            {
                if (!process.HasExited)
                {
                    process.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't help.I wrote similar code but still have same problem

Comment: ok, what are you doing with the excel then, reading/copying or writing?

Comment: Exporting data from WPF app.The problem that I am exporting 2000-3000 files in the loop.Each time I close properly excel  + I kill all excel processes to be 100% sure that no  excel on the background but seldom I have a problem in the dll.